# Django capture url with "%20" and redirect

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm not good at regexes. I need to redirect a url that looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/files/BIENES%20INMUEBLES%20DISPONIBLES.pdf?39
```

How can I capture it with a url pattern?

I tried this:

```
url(r'^files/BIENES%20INMUEBLES%20DISPONIBLES.pdf?39$', views.MyRedirectView.as_view()),
```

But it doesn't work, I get a 404. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against) Django does not account for GET query parameters when matching urls. So the `?39` part will be skipped in the matching process.

However, you can use a pattern like this (it matches uppercase letters, numbers and the character %):

```
url(r'^files/(?P<name>[A-Z\d%]*)\.pdf$', view, name='whatever')
```

And then in the view, you could do something like:

```
def view(request, name):
    query_keys = [key for key in request.GET]  # query_keys = [39]
    ...
```

**Why your pattern did not work**

The pattern you originally used did not work because the urls that matched it had to end in `pdf39` or `pd39`. That's because the question mark in regular expressions has a special meaning and makes the preceding character *optional*. Note also that the dot character signifies *any* character. To make these characters not to have their special meaning you can use `\?` and `\.`.